# Database is not updated after button clicked for Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view that contains a checkbox column and another column for info. Once checked or unchecked I want to update the db based on what occurred for the checkbox. However, after clicking the button it seems that the Checkbox checked property value is erased and goes back to its original state before the onClick event occurs and the database is never updated.

ASPX

```
<div>

    <asp:gridview runat="server" id="MeasuresGrid"  autogeneratecolumns="False" cssclass="SelectionHeader" onrowdatabound="MeasuresGrid_OnRowDataBound" datakeynames="SubSectionId">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#cce1ec"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Applicable Measures?" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="MeasureChckBox" CommandName="CheckBox" Checked='<%# Eval("IsSelected") %>' CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" runat="server" />
              </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Measure" DataField="SubSection">

                </asp:BoundField>


             </Columns>
    </asp:gridview>
</div>

<asp:updatepanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left">
            <asp:button id="btnCancel" runat="server" text="Cancel" cssclass="hrsaSkingreybtn" />
        </td>
        <td style="width: 50%; text-align: right">
            <asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" text="Save" cssclass="hrsaSkingreybtn" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:updatepanel>
```

ASPX.cs

```
protected void MeasuresGrid_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            var measureChckBox = (e.Row.FindControl("MeasureChckBox") as CheckBox);
            foreach (var x in MeasurePrefixArray)
            {
                if (e.Row.Cells[1].Text.StartsWith(x))
                {
                    if (measureChckBox != null)
                    {
                        measureChckBox.Checked = true;
                        measureChckBox.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (GridViewRow row in MeasuresGrid.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                //Retrieve isSelected value
                var selectQuery =
                    @"select IsSelected from MHF.FlexMeasureSelection where RptInstanceId = @ReportInstanceId and SubSectionId = @SubSectionId";
                var dataKey = MeasuresGrid.DataKeys[row.RowIndex];
                if (dataKey != null)
                {
                    if (dataKey.Value != null)
                    {
                        subSectionId = Convert.ToInt32(dataKey.Value);
                    }
                }
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn = DbAgent.selfRef().getConnection("default");
                var command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text
                };
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportInstanceId", apSess.ReportInstanceID);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubSectionId", subSectionId);
                var isSelected = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

                var chk = (CheckBox) row.Cells[0].FindControl("MeasureChckBox");
                var updateQuery =
                    @"update MHF.FlexMeasureSelection set IsSelected = @IsSelected where RptInstanceId = @ReportInstanceId and SubSectionId = @SubSectionId";
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn = DbAgent.selfRef().getConnection("default");
                var command1 = new SqlCommand(updateQuery, conn)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text
                };
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RptInstanceId", apSess.ReportInstanceID);
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubSectionId", subSectionId);
                if (chk != null)
                {
                    //handle deletion from A330 Data Table  and disable display from form
                    var checkedVal = 0;
                    if (isSelected == 1 && !chk.Checked)
                    {
                        //update FlexMeasureSelection Table
                        checkedVal = 0;
                        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSelected", checkedVal);
                        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        lbConfirmationMessage.Visible = true;
                        lbConfirmationMessage.Text = @"Selections have been saved";

                    }
                    else if (isSelected == 0 && chk.Checked) //enable display with form
                    {
                        //update FlexMeasureSelection Table
                        checkedVal = 1;
                        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsSelected", checkedVal);
                        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        lbConfirmationMessage.Visible = true;
                        lbConfirmationMessage.Text = @"Selections have been saved";

                    }
                    conn.Close();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppLogger.selfRef().log("Error in SelectionPage.aspx.cs btnSave_OnClick", AppLogger.logLevel.error);
                var ex2 = new AppException(CORE.Utilities.AppException.ErrorCode.DB, ORHP.AppObjects.AppIni.selfRef().XmlErrorCodes, ex);
                throw ex2;
            }
        }
        MeasuresGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: How are you binding the `asp:GridView` is it inside `!IsPostBack`?

Comment: Its not in ispostbck

Comment: can you paste the BindGridView method?

Comment: Why you placed Button inside Update panel? Did it affect gridview on click event of button?

Comment: @naveen I am only using the MeasuresGrid.DataBind()

Comment: @RojalinSahoo It didnt impact it, cant figure it out